# How to change HTML element's id value in a for loop

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, view

I'm trying to insert rating system in my asp.net project.The problem is that in every tutorial that i saw, there are two separate ratings, one that shows the rating of the entity and another one which is for your rate(most of them are like adding new comment with rating).So I'm trying to use only one 5 stars rating, showing the avarage rating and also changing color on hover and click.That is my logic:

```
@for (var i = 1; i <= Model.Photo.Rating.Rate; i++)
                            {
                                <span class="starGlowN"  id="Rating+i" "onclick="CRate(i)" onmouseover="CRateOver(i)" onmouseout="CRateOut(i)"></span>
                            }
                            @for (var i = (Model.Photo.Rating.Rate + 1); i <= 5; i++)
                            {
                                <span class="starFadeN"></span>
                            }}
```

All the functions (Crate,CRateOver,CrateOut) take the is of the span class StarGlown and change the class name, that way the stars change their color.

How can i change the id in the loop (Rating1,rating2),i've tried with  id="Rating+i" but this does not work, can you help with the right syntax

Comment: `id="@("Rating" + i)"`

Comment: or `id="Rating@i"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@for (var i = 1; i <= Model.Photo.Rating.Rate; i++)
                    {
                         <span class="starGlowN" id="Rating" + @i onclick="CRate(@i)" onmouseover="CRateOver(@i)" onmouseout="CRateOut(@i)" onmouseout="CRateOut(@i)"></span>
                        }
```

Comment: @freedomn-m i think it is correct: id = "Rating" + @i

Comment: @freedomn-m i did test

Comment: okey @freedomn-m Why don't you fix it over my code?

Comment: no worries - was just pointing out what looked liked typos (quote before onclick `"onclick`) in your original.

Comment: @freedomn-m I opened and tested a project for you :)